# How to concatenate strings with function calls while using echo?

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I want to use the values returned from two function calls in my echo'ed html string.

`<li><a href="the_permalink()">the_title()</a></li>`

The following works fine:

```
echo '<li><a href="';
echo the_permalink();
echo '">';
echo the_title();
echo '</a></li>';
```

... but how do I get them all in one single statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<li><a href="', the_permalink(), '">', the_title(), '</a></li>';
```

Comment: The dot version evaluates all items (e.g. calling the functions) to be concatenated before calling echo. The comma version evaluates and prints the parameters, one after another, while running the echo construct. (A comment in the PHP manual -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#78898 -- explains this better.) Since, you do not want the_permalink() to be evaluated before echo is called and '<li><a href="' is printed, the dot version is not what you want.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you are having problems is because **the_permalink()** and **the_title()** do not return, they echo. Instead use **get_permalink()** and **$post->post_title**. Remember **get_permalink()** requires the post id ($post->ID) as a parameter. I know this is irritating and counter-intuitive, but it's how Wordpress works (see subjectivity in comments to this answer.)

This explains why the second example works in your initial question. If you call function that prints from within a string, the echo will output before the end of the string.

So this:

```
echo ' this should be before the link: '.the_permalink().' But it is not.';
```

will not work as expected. Instead, it will output this:

```
http://example.com this should be before the link: But it is not.
```

In PHP you can use both single and double quotes. When I am building strings with HTML I generally begin the string with a single quote, that way, I can use HTML-compatible double quotes within the string without escaping.

**So to round it up, it would look something like:**

```
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
```

Or as you originally requested, to simply escape them, put a backslash before the quote. Like so (the single quotes have been removed)

```
echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink($post->ID)."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
```

This is of course assuming you are calling this from *within the loop*, otherwise a bit more than this would be required to get the desired output.

Comment: That's the thing I hate most about wordpress: functions are supposed to *return* values not *print* them; I can print return values myself.

Comment: I agree. However, these functions were created for people who know little about PHP (which is 95% of the WP community). the_title() is more newbie friendly than echo $post->post_title. This is one of the many reasons WP has been so successful. For me, it comes second nature, and I use both versions, depending on placement.

Comment: True, but `echo the_title()` isn't much harder, `echo` is familiar to anyone I think, and leaves more freedom to the developer. Functions were refactored in later version to support both echo and return, but there is hardly any consistency in that.

Comment: My argument against "echo the_title()" is redundancy. Templates are far prettier when those 20-30 'echos' you are suggesting are omitted and a template friendly function is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', the_permalink(), the_title() );
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason, links are not parsed correctly.

Comment: Do your functions return strings? - what do you mean not parsed correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I test? Well, it doesn't show as a link, the link itself is shown followed by title, all text, no clickable link.

Comment: post an example of the link that is generated - there must be another problem if the other solutions on this page don't work either - are you sure your original works?

Comment: Example output: http://localhost/tone/2010/02/07/review-7/Review #7

--- Yes, mine works.

Answer (score 1):

Using concatenation (line breaks not required):

```
echo '<li><a href="'
 . the_permalink()
 . '">'
 . the_title()
 . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: @Mark: PHP uses a '.' for string concatenation! Your statement would attempt to add the numeric values of the strings together

Comment: hehe - I got into trouble the other day for declaring an array in JavaScript literal fashion

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<li><a href=".the_permalink().">".the_title()."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php the_title_attribute() ?>`. It displays or returns the title of the current post. It somewhat duplicates the functionality of the_title(), but provides a 'clean' version of the title by stripping HTML tags and converting certain characters (including quotes) to their character entity equivalent.